# this in Phaser game JS

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so I recently started learning JS and now trying to use Phaser to make games.
In the piece of code below,

1- is the author referring to mainState by using "this"??
2- there is no variable defined for bird. where does it store data then??

```
// Initialize Phaser, and creates a 400x490px game
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 490, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameDiv');

// Creates a new 'main' state that will contain the game
var mainState = {

    // Function called first to load all the assets
    preload: function() { 
        // Change the background color of the game
        game.stage.backgroundColor = '#71c5cf';

        // Load the bird sprite
        game.load.image('bird', 'assets/bird.png');  

        // Load the pipe sprite
        game.load.image('pipe', 'assets/pipe.png');      
    },

    // Fuction called after 'preload' to setup the game 
    create: function() { 
        // Set the physics system
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        // Display the bird on the screen
        this.bird = this.game.add.sprite(100, 245, 'bird');

        // Add gravity to the bird to make it fall
        game.physics.arcade.enable(this.bird);
        this.bird.body.gravity.y = 1000; 

        // Call the 'jump' function when the spacekey is hit
        var spaceKey = this.game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
        spaceKey.onDown.add(this.jump, this); 

        // Create a group of 20 pipes
        this.pipes = game.add.group();
        this.pipes.enableBody = true;
        this.pipes.createMultiple(20, 'pipe');  

        // Timer that calls 'addRowOfPipes' ever 1.5 seconds
        this.timer = this.game.time.events.loop(1500, this.addRowOfPipes, this);           

        // Add a score label on the top left of the screen
        this.score = 0;
        this.labelScore = this.game.add.text(20, 20, "0", { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ffffff" });  
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*this* in the code you posted refers to mainState as you inferred. Using this.valueName creates a new value on the mainState object.

See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for more info on the this keyword and what it refers to when used in different places. This example from the linked page is relevant to your code:

```
var o = {
  prop: 37,
  f: function() {
    return this.prop;
  }
};

console.log(o.f()); // logs 37
```

It stores the data as usual, for all intents and purposes it performs the same function as adding another value outside the function as normal. And could be accessed with mainState.bird.

```
var mainState = {
    bird : game.addBird(...)
}
```

Comment: It's worth adding that Phaser will automatically populate the `mainState` object with a bunch of properties so you never have to access the `game` global directly. For example: `this.game.input.keyboard.` should really be written as: `this.input.keyboard`. The same goes for `this.game.add` - can just be `this.add` and so on. Please see the docs page for more details and a list of all the properties you can use.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, the `this` keyword in the `mainState` object's functions points to the `mainState` object itself.
2. The `bird` variable is defined on the `mainState` object itself with:

   ```
   // Display the bird on the screen
   this.bird = this.game.add.sprite(100, 245, 'bird');
   ```

Comment: so basically this.bird makes a new variable named bird... right?

Comment: @vvvsg Yes, but it's tied to the `mainState` object, i.e. is a property of the `mainState` object.